# What are the disadvantages of directly calling function inside generator function over wrapping that function inside Call in redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

From redux-saga doc I got to the conclusion that call function is like the actions which  return the plain object and  helps in the testing and also helps the developer to understand the code easily. But what are the other real advantages of using Call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience in using redux-saga for almost more than a year, having functions invoked using `yield call(fn)` provides future proofing in some of your function implementation / invokation.

So if somewhere in the future, you decided to make `fn` to be another `generator function`, or even an `async function` you know it would still work since it was invoked using `yield call(fn)`.